# Convert visual selection to visual line selection in vim

Tags: vim

I have a visual selection in vim spanning several lines and i want to "convert" that into a visual line selection. Preferably in a succint way if possible. Without just selecting the same lines again ofcourse, that doesn't seem like the vim way to do it.

I feel I could probably figure it out but I'm betting someone here knows a neat way to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To switch from visual selection to visual line selection just press `V` (uppercase).

To switch back from visual line selection to visual selection, you can press `v` (lowercase) again.

Comment: You can also re-select your previous visual selecting with `gv`.

Comment: And don't forget `^V` to switch to a block selection.